# Hector_Slam ROSMake Error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I Read Text File In Hector_slam Folder (Readme.txt) And Try To Make Hector_Slam And ROSMAKE give me error :

```
ros@ubuntu:~$ rosmake hector_slam
```

[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['hector_slam']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/ros/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130111-163128
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['hector_slam'] to:
['hector_map_server', 'hector_mapping', 'hector_imu_attitude_to_tf', 'hector_nav_msgs', 'hector_compressed_map_transport', 'hector_map_tools', 'hector_trajectory_server', 'hector_slam_launch', 'hector_geotiff']
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "ros" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "common_msgs" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "geometry" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "ros_comm" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "image_common" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "vision_opencv" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/rosmake", line 55, in 
if rma.main():
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 783, in main
self.build_or_recurse(p)
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 315, in build_or_recurse
self.build_or_recurse(d)
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
for d in self.dependency_tracker.get_deps_1(p):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/parallel_build.py", line 100, in get_deps_1
potential_dependencies = self.rospack.get_depends(package, implicit=False)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 188, in get_depends
m = self.get_manifest(name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 133, in get_manifest
return self._load_manifest(name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 172, in _load_manifest
retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/manifest.py", line 376, in parse_manifest_file
_static_rosdep_view = init_rospack_interface()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 55, in init_rospack_interface
lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 108, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
lookup = RosdepLookup.create_from_rospkg(sources_loader=sources_loader)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 319, in create_from_rospkg
lookup._load_all_views(loader=sources_loader)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 464, in _load_all_views
self._load_view_dependencies(resource_name, loader)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 486, in _load_view_dependencies
loader.load_view(view_key, db, verbose=self.verbose)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 525, in load_view
rosdep_db.set_view_data(view_name, source.rosdep_data, view_dependencies, view_name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/model.py", line 89, in set_view_data
self._rosdep_db[view_name] = RosdepDatabaseEntry(rosdep_data.copy(), view_dependencies, origin)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/rosmake", line 55, in 
if rma.main():
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 783, in main
self.build_or_recurse(p)
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 315, in build_or_recurse
self.build_or_recurse(d)
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
for d in self.dependency_tracker.get_deps_1(p):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/parallel_build.py", line 100, in get_deps_1
potential_dependencies = self.rospack.get_depends(package, implicit=False)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 188, in get_depends
m = self.get_manifest(name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 133, in get_manifest
return self._load_manifest(name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 172, in _load_manifest
retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/manifest.py", line 376, in parse_manifest_file
_static_rosdep_view = init_rospack_interface()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 55, in init_rospack_interface
lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 108, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
lookup = RosdepLookup.create_from_rospkg(sources_loader=sources_loader)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 319, in create_from_rospkg
lookup._load_all_views(loader=sources_loader)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 464, in _load_all_views
self._load_view_dependencies(resource_name, loader)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 486, in _load_view_dependencies
loader.load_view(view_key, db, verbose=self.verbose)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 525, in load_view
rosdep_db.set_view_data(view_name, source.rosdep_data, view_dependencies, view_name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/model.py", line 89, in set_view_data
self._rosdep_db[view_name] = RosdepDatabaseEntry(rosdep_data.copy(), view_dependencies, origin)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52052/hector_slam-rosmake-error/) by [Danial](https://answers.ros.org/users/3950/danial/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I saw this issue before, it was related to performing rosmake on a fuerte package when groovy was installed (likely the whole dry wet thing).

If you're running Ubuntu, I'd suggest first trying to install the package from the repo: `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-hector-slam`

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ebozgul](https://answers.ros.org/users/4340/ebozgul/) on 2013-06-13**:
This worked for me, when I was getting the error: "[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names." after i use command "rosmake hector_slam"